# Changing width of last card in deckgrid

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i am using angular-deckgrid to display the images. I have two columns for displaying images with **column-1-2** class as described in docs inside a container . Now in some cases, their is only one image in the last row , in such cases i want to make that image take the whole width instead of 50% of the space .

Now this is how the two columns are rendered :

```
<div deckgrid="" class="deckgrid ng-isolate-scope" source="loves">
   <div data-ng-repeat="column in columns" class="column column-1-2">
      <div data-ng-repeat="card in column" data-ng-include="cardTemplate" class="ng-scope"> "my card layout here" </div>
      <div data-ng-repeat="card in column" data-ng-include="cardTemplate" class="ng-scope"> "my card layout here" </div>
      <div data-ng-repeat="card in column" data-ng-include="cardTemplate" class="ng-scope"> "my card layout here" </div>
   </div>
   <div data-ng-repeat="column in columns" class="column column-1-2">
      <div data-ng-repeat="card in column" data-ng-include="cardTemplate" class="ng-scope"> "my card layout here" </div>
      <div data-ng-repeat="card in column" data-ng-include="cardTemplate" class="ng-scope"> "my card layout here" </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see , first column has three and second column has two .. I want that third card in the first column to take the whole width .. 
Not able to do it in controller because the template is not rendered yet .
Using css i was something in this direction ::

```
.column-1-2 div[data-ng-repeat]:last-child {
    width:200%!important;
}
```

but how do i check if the first column and second column has unequal child in css .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get it wrong but you can use $last property of the ng-repeat combined to the ng-class. It will add the class `mylast-child` to the last div of the ng-repeat

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="card in column" 
      data-ng-include="cardTemplate" class="ng-scope"
      ng-class="{'mylast-child': $last}" > 
             "my card layout here"
 </div>


 .mylast-child {
     width:200%!important;
 }
```

the ng-repeat have also other interesting option :

```
Variable |  Type     |  Details
--------------------------------
$index   |   number |    iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
$first   |   boolean |  true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
$middle  |  boolean | true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator.
$last    |   boolean |  true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.
$even    |   boolean |  true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).
$odd     |   boolean |  true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).
```

Comment: actually these ng-repeats are added dynamically from that plugin , its not in my template to edit

Comment: which plugin ? you cannot change the html ?

Comment: angular-deckgrid , i just need to include this :: -
<div deckgrid class="deckgrid" source="loves">
  " my card content here " 
</div>

the html above is generated by the plugin

Comment: ok. sorry i can't help you on this. i don't know css well but it should be a way to get the last item of a node

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Angular in-built functions

```
var firstChildCount =  angular.element(angular.element(".column")[0]).find('div').length;
var secondChildCount =  angular.element(angular.element(".column")[1]).find('div').length;

if(firstChildCount  !== secondChildCount ){
     //Apply CSS
}
```